# Live wallpaper animation force closing when I add more than 10 frames?

Tags: java, android, animation, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to make a simple livewallpaper out of a series of boot animation .pngs...

I'm using

```
private static final int NUM_RES = 9;
        private final Bitmap[] mPics = new Bitmap[NUM_RES];
        CubeEngine() {
            Resources res = getResources();
            for (int i = 0; i< NUM_RES; i++) {
                int id = res.getIdentifier("boot_0010" + (i + 1), "drawable", "minghai.wallpaper");
                mPics[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);
            }
        }
```

**9 seems to be the highest I can go. If i set NUM_RES to anything over 9 i get a force close.**

All my files are labeled...
boot_00101.png
boot_00102.png
boot_00103.png
boot_00104.png
boot_00105.png
boot_00106.png
boot_00107.png
boot_00108.png
boot_00109.png
boot_00110.png
boot_00111.png
boot_00112.png
boot_00113.png
boot_00114.png
and so on...I have about 50 images im trying to use

Anyone know what I should be doing?

LOGCAT:

```
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1115)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at minghai.wallpaper.YayoiWallpaper$CubeEngine.drawYayoi(YayoiWallpaper.java:166)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at minghai.wallpaper.YayoiWallpaper$CubeEngine.drawFrame(YayoiWallpaper.java:144)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at minghai.wallpaper.YayoiWallpaper$CubeEngine.onOffsetsChanged(YayoiWallpaper.java:117)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.doOffsetsChanged(WallpaperService.java:669)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:847)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-21 19:18:43.108: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6475):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

@Yok
Thank you so much that did the trick....to an extent, i can't seem to go past 30 I get a memory error. Sorry to ask, but would you happen to know of a more efficient way to simply get an animation like i'm trying to achieve.

```
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:346)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:372)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at minghai.wallpaper.YayoiWallpaper$CubeEngine.<init>(YayoiWallpaper.java:60)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at minghai.wallpaper.YayoiWallpaper.onCreateEngine(YayoiWallpaper.java:35)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:814)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-22 04:35:03.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Use "adb logcat" to check what exception is being thrown.  Add the stacktrace to your question if you still need help.

Comment: alright, i updated the first post

Comment: check my answer and replace your for loop line with one I suggested.

Comment: please open new question for another exception. and revert existing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with your for loop change :

`"boot_0010" + (i + 1)` to `"boot_00" + (100+ (i + 1))`

Changed loop should look like :

```
       for (int i = 0; i< NUM_RES; i++) {
            int id = res.getIdentifier("boot_00" + (100 + (i + 1)), "drawable", "minghai.wallpaper");
            mPics[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);
        }
```

Problem with your loop was that earlier it used to get **boot_001010** instead of **boot_00110** for 10th image. And same was reason for null pointer exception as image with boot_001010 is not present.

Comment: Thank you so much! that soved the problem! However, I found a new one, maybe you could take a look up top I edited the main post again

Comment: @brybam Please revert back newly entered information and open new question for same.

Answer (score 0):

When *i* is 9, the expression `"boot_0010" + (i + 1)` evaluates to the string `boot_001010`; you probably wanted it to be `boot_00110`.